# handle empty Json Array from object

Tags: c#, json

I have a json object that returns two empty arrays
       **"subQuestions": []** and   **"answers": []**

I have created classes for the object, but I cannot get it to work, 
this is what I have so far.

Object

```
   "questions": [
        {
            "questionId": "1",
            "question": "Ipsum",
            "helpText": null,
            "questionType": "MultipleChoice",
            "answerChoices": [
                {
                    "answerChoiceId": "b2b-2.01-answer1",
                    "value": "Lorem",
                    "subQuestions": []
                }
            ],
            "answers": []
        }
```

Classes

```
    public class AnswerChoice
    {
    public string answerChoiceId { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public List<object> subQuestions { get; set; }
}

public class Question
    {
    public string questionId { get; set; }
    public string question { get; set; }
    public object helpText { get; set; }
    public string questionType { get; set; }
    public List<AnswerChoice> answerChoices { get; set; }
    public List<object> answers { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectRoot
    {
    public string productId { get; set; }
    public List<Question> questions { get; set; }
}




var jsonBody = new ObjectRoot()
     {
      productId = productId,
      questions = new[]
       {
        new Question() {
        questionId = "b2b-2.01",
        question ="Vad är syftet med ert engagemang hos oss?",
        helpText = null,
        questionType = "MultiChoise",
        answerChoices = new []{
        new AnswerChoice{
        answerChoiceId = "",
        value = "",
        **HERE is what it gets tricky for me**
        }
       }
      }
     }
   };
```

The tricky part for me is after value = "", and the subQuestion object needs to be added, have tried multiple ways but no luck.

Comment: Your code and objects don't match e.g. what's `TransaktionsKontoAnswerChoice` and what exactly _becomes tricky_ can you elaborate?

Comment: Where this `TQuestion` and `TransaktionsKontoAnswerChoice` comes from? you didn't include any classes with these names.

Comment: @JSteward Sorry about that, it was a typo. edited now.
The tricky part is how to build the object so it matches the classes.

Answer (score 0):

In your classes all collections is `List` not array. So to make it work you need to call `ToList` extension method. And for empty collections just call `List` constructor

```
var jsonBody = new ObjectRoot()
{
    productId = "productId",
    questions = new[]
    {
        new Question() {
            questionId = "b2b-2.01",
            question ="Vad är syftet med ert engagemang hos oss?",
            helpText = null,
            questionType = "MultiChoise",
            answerChoices = new []{
                new AnswerChoice{
                    answerChoiceId = "",
                    value = "",
                    subQuestions = new List<object>() // empty collection                        
                }
            }.ToList(),
            answers = new List<object>()
        }
    }.ToList()
};
```

Comment: Why down vote? this looks like it will work for me.